# Secure PHP functions with array?

Tags: php

I am currently creating a small PHP site that will have multiple different access levels. Some people will have access to all portions (a,b,c,d) and some will only have access to specific portions (like b,d).

Currently, I have users log in and there username/password is verified against stored credentials in the mysql database. Additionally, at login I create an array which lists all of the functions a user has access to. I then store the array in their session variable. Each PHP page has the following code up at the top of the page,

```
   session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["is_auth"])) {
  header("location: login.php");
    exit;
   }
```

My question is,
How to I limit access to functions/pages? Should I have each function once again call the database and check if the user can access the function or is it enough to just verify that the particular function is in the array which is stored in the user session.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: suckey to call the db that often ,could store there access in a session

Comment: there is no built-in way to do that, you have to write the logic yourself. based on the code you provided, you clearly already know the basics of how to write such code, now you just have to get creative and implement it. i wouldn't use any answer you get, figure it out on your own, great learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session content can be assumed to be secure as the client can't access it.

If your login process set a `$_SESSION` option you can check this.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["is_auth"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
// empty() matches to bool(false) and int(0), but throws no notice if index is undefined.
if (empty($_SESSION["allowed_area"]["area_a"])) {
    header("location: access_denied.php");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the user credentials in database on each page, as Session variables are secure.

But you might check it after some time because let's say if in your Admin Panel you removed a user or locked his account or changed his password, but before that user was already logged in. So in that case if you don't verify within your database the user will not be logged out and he will be logged in until he close his browser (he may not deliberately close it to keep logged in to your website), you should take care of this possibility.

The second problem is session hijacking, if someone gets the session cookie of your valid user than he would also be using your website. So you should use `session_regenerate_id(true);` on each of your pages so that each time new session id is assigned to the user and previous one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

About how to grant access to any user at any resources of the server, what I do is save all the data on the session and after, in each user request, seek on the data base if the user (or rather, the role of the user) has permissions enough as to access this resource.

I recommend to use a framework as codeigniter (it is very easy to learn how it works, and there are thousands of tutorials), and there is a library call [ion-auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) made by Ben Edmunds. It has a login, signup (with auto email sending to activate the account -if you configure-), recovery password, a couple of secure functions to get access to the users.

For the permissions, what I use is this library:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Permissions
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        if (!method_exists( $this->ion_auth_model, $method) )
        {
            throw new Exception('Undefined method Ion_auth::' . $method . '() called');
        }

        return call_user_func_array( array($this->ion_auth_model, $method), $arguments);
    }

    public function __get($var)
    {
        return get_instance()->$var;
    }

    public function control(){
        // controla la session

        if(!$this->session->userdata('id')) redirect(base_url("/login"), "refresh");    

        // valida los permisos
        $group = $this->permissions_model->lookUpGroup($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $menu = $this->permissions_model->lookUpPermission($this->uri->segment(1), $group->group_id);
        //echo "url: ".$this->uri->segment(1)." grup: ".$group->group_id."<br>";
        //var_dump($menu);
        //die();
        if((!$menu || empty($menu)) || $menu->read == 0 && $menu->menu_id != 12 ){
            redirect(base_url("/dashboard"), "refresh");
        }           

        // retorna permisos
        $menu = $this->permissions_model->getByLink($this->uri->segment(1));
        return $permisos = $this->permissions_model->permissions($menu->id, $this->session->userdata('user_id'));

    }

    public function getMenu(){  
        $ci = &get_instance();
        if($ci->session->userdata("id"))
        {
            $user_id = $ci->session->userdata("id");
            $father_query = "SELECT  u.id usuario, ug.user_id, ug.group_id, p.menu_id, p.read, p.insert, p.update, p.delete, p.group_id, m.*
            FROM users u
            JOIN users_groups ug        ON u.id = ug.user_id
            JOIN permisos p             ON ug.group_id = p.group_id
            JOIN menus m                ON p.menu_id = m.id
            WHERE u.id = ".$user_id."   AND m.active=1
            AND m.parent=0
            ORDER BY m.orden
            ";
            $query_padres = $ci->db->query($father_query);

            if($query_padres->num_rows()>0)
            {       
                foreach($query_padres->result() as $field)
                {
                    $consulta_hijos = "SELECT  u.id usuario, ug.user_id, ug.group_id, p.menu_id, p.read, p.insert, p.update, p.delete, p.group_id, m.*
                    FROM users u
                    JOIN users_groups ug        ON u.id = ug.user_id
                    JOIN permisos p             ON ug.group_id = p.group_id
                    JOIN menus m                ON p.menu_id = m.id
                    WHERE u.id = ".$user_id."   AND m.active=1
                    AND m.parent=".$field->id."
                    AND p.read=1
                    ORDER BY m.orden";
                    $sub_query = $ci->db->query($consulta_hijos);
                    if($sub_query->num_rows()>0){
                        $submenus = '';
                        $active_menu = '';
                        $active_menu_collapse = '';
                        foreach ($sub_query->result() as $result_dos) {
                                    if ($ci->uri->segment(1) == $result_dos->link && $ci->uri->segment(2) == $result_dos->sublink) {
                                        $submenus .= "<li class='active'><a href='". base_url($result_dos->link."/".$result_dos->sublink)."'><i class='".$result_dos->iconpath."'></i> ".$ci->lang->line($result_dos->descripcion)."</a></li>";
                                        $active_menu = 'active';
                                        $active_menu_collapse = 'collapse in';
                                    }else{
                                        $submenus .= "<li><a href='". base_url($result_dos->link."/".$result_dos->sublink)."'><i class='".$result_dos->iconpath."'></i> ".$ci->lang->line($result_dos->descripcion)."</a></li>";
                                    }
                        }

                        echo    "<li class='".$active_menu."'>
                                    <a href='javascript:;'><i class='".$field->iconpath."'></i><span class='title'>".$ci->lang->line($field->descripcion)."</span><span class='arrow'></span></a>
                                    <ul class='sub-menu'>
                                    ".$submenus."
                                    </ul>
                                </li>";
                    }
                    else if (($ci->uri->segment(1) == $field->link && $ci->uri->segment(2) == $field->sublink) || $ci->uri->segment(1) == '') {
                        echo "  <li class='active'>
                                    <a href='".base_url($field->link."/".$field->sublink)."'>
                                        <i class='".$field->iconpath."'></i> 
                                        <span class='title'>".$ci->lang->line($field->descripcion)."
                                        <span class='selected'></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<li>
                                <a href='".base_url($field->link."/".$field->sublink)."'>
                                    <i class='".$field->iconpath."'></i> 
                                    <span class='title'>".$ci->lang->line($field->descripcion)."</span>
                                    <span class='selected'></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After of this I create a father controller on the core folder (from which one extend every controllers that you want to guarantee the correct access). A example of a controller on core folder:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main_Father extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //session_start();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        if($this->getPermissions())
        {
            //make some things before pass control to the authentic controller
        }
        else 
            redirect(base_url());
    }
    private function getPermissions()
    {
        $this->user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        if($this->user)
        {
            //$this->data["permissions"]    = $this->permissions->control();
            if($this->permissions->control())
            {
                //make any function
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(strpos(base_url(uri_string()),"login")==false)
                redirect(base_url('/login'.$url));
            else return false
        }
    }
}
```

And the last element... the Permission_model

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Permissions_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function get_all(){
        $query = $this->db->get('groups');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function getAll(){
        $user_row = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group(1, $user_row->id)){
            $query = $this->db
                ->select('p.*, g.name AS grupo, m.descripcion AS menu')
                ->join('groups g','p.group_id = g.id')
                ->join('menus m', 'p.menu_id = m.id')
                ->where('p.group_id !=', 1)
                ->get('permisos p');
        }else{
            $query = $this->db
                ->select('p.*, g.name AS grupo, m.descripcion AS menu')
                ->join('groups g','p.group_id = g.id')
                ->join('menus m', 'p.menu_id = m.id')
                ->get('permisos p');      
        }
        return $query->result();
    }

    //buscar
    function lookUp(/*$perpage,$start*/){
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('permisos.id AS id,
            menus.descripcion AS menu,
            groups.id AS id_grupo,
            groups.description  AS grupo,
            permisos.read AS Leer,
            permisos.insert AS Insertar,
            permisos.update AS Actualizar,
            permisos.delete AS Borrar,
            permisos.exportar AS Exportar,
            permisos.imprimir AS Imprimir')
            ->join('menus',     'menus.id = permisos.menu_id', 'inner')
            ->join('groups',    'groups.id = permisos.group_id', 'inner');

        if($where = $this->input->post('buscar', TRUE))
            $query = $this->db->where('permisos.id =', $where)
                ->or_where("menus.descripcion LIKE '%".$where."%'")
                ->or_where("groups.description LIKE '%".$where."%'");

        $query = $this->db
            ->get('permisos');
        return $query->result('array');
    }

    //count_buscar
    function count_lookUp($perpage,$start){
        $query = $this->db
            ->join('menus',     'menus.id = permisos.menu_id', 'inner')
            ->join('groups',    'groups.id = permisos.group_id', 'inner');
        if($where = $this->input->post('buscar', TRUE))
            $query = $this->db->where('id =', $where);
        $query = $this->db->limit($perpage,$start)
            ->get('permisos');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    function getByLink($link){
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('id')
            ->where('link',$link)
            ->get('menus');
        return $query->row();
    }
    //buscarPermiso
    function lookupPermission($url, $perfil){
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('p.read,p.menu_id')
            ->join('menus m', 'm.id = p.menu_id')
            ->where('p.group_id', $perfil)
            ->like('m.link', $url)
            ->get('permisos p');
        return $query->row();
    }
    //buscarGrupo
    function lookUpGroup($usuario){
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('group_id')
            ->where('user_id', $usuario)
            ->get('users_groups');
        return $query->row();
    }
    function permissions($menu, $id_usuario) {
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('u.id, up.group_id, p.*')
            ->join('users_groups up', 'up.user_id = u.id')
            ->join('permisos p', 'p.group_id = up.group_id')
            ->where('u.id =', $id_usuario)
            ->where('p.menu_id =', $menu)
            ->limit('1')
            ->get('users u');
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

PS: 1º) I don´t like a lot the getMenu function, it doesn't respect the MVC pattern cannons, also the queries are not safe (it must to use the parametrized method ?). 2º) The html created by this function can be changed. 3º) Most of the code described here is not mine... the ion_auth library is made by Ben Edmunds and the Permissions code is made by a unknown "artist". 4º)There are many things on the permissions_model upgradable if you are punctilious...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment!