# Insert/Update using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I've read similar questions and answers on Codeigniter update but not able to solve my problem.

I have a user table and a user_role table. The user table has information like userid, name, address etc and the user_role table has userid and role_id where role_id s are ids for roles such as Entry, Edit, View etc.

Now an admin can change the role of a user and update the user information. The roles are shown as checkboxes. To update the roles of user, I have deleted all the rows for that user in user_role table and inserted new roles. I have tried this:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['role'])) {

            $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('user_role');

    foreach ($_POST['role'] as $val) {

            $arr['user_id'] = $id;
            $arr['role_id'] = $val;                 
            $this->db->insert('user_role', $arr);
            }
    }
    else {
            $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('user_role');
    }
```

If all the checkboxes are uncheked, then all the rows are deleted. It is working fine. But this does not seem to be a proper way. Please guide.

Comment: you need to update the user_role to pass the user id

Comment: If you want more info about the permissions by roles on codeigniter you can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126013/secure-php-functions-with-array/37126471?noredirect=1#comment61833227_37126471

Comment: its clear - your code deletes all user roles if none of the checkboxes are checked - what do you expect? so the only thing which bothers you is the else block just handle it differently

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($_POST['role']){
     foreach ($_POST['role'] as $val) {

        $arr['user_id'] = $id;
        $arr['role_id'] = $val;                 

      // You need to run Update query. do not need to delete the records every time.
        $where = array('user_id'=>$arr['user_id']);
        $this->modelname->updateRecord($tablename,$arr,$where);

         //It will update the records on post

    }
}
```

Comment: thats wrong what if there are values in the db which are not checked in the form ?
This values should be deleted - his approach is fine

Comment: In Db He can take the value NULL by default Even when he delete it will goes to Null.

Comment: you didn't even understood what i wrote, your example just handles all checked attributes - but what about those who are in the database and are not checked ?

Comment: Binod, you didn't get my problem. I had to delete the records as user_id/role_id pairs have to be unique. @sintakone, you are right. I want to solve it in a more concise way.

Answer (score 0):

First. Where is $id defined??

Second. Codeigniter has a library that makes not necessary the use of $_POST or $_GET.

Third. Is necessary that one user has more than one role?? I recommend you to use a select like:

```
<select name="role">
     <option value="user">User</option>
     <option value="employee">Employee</option>
     <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Maybe you need to use an id of the role in the values of the options... something like

```
 <option value="1">User</option>
 <option value="2">Employee</option>
 <option value="3">Admin</option>
```

Fourth. If you want update... why don't you use the update method of the codeigneter ORM. In this way, I had made a file called general_model.php placed on the models folder (are you using this folder and the MVC pattern??) where I have something like a facade between the ORM and the controllers. One of the functions is update:

```
public function update($tablename, $data, $where)
{                   
    foreach($where as $key=>$value)
        $this->db->where($key, $value); 
    $this->db->update($tablename, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)    return TRUE;
    else                                    return FALSE;
}
```

An example of use from the controller, for your case (using only one role by user) could be:

```
$this->general_model->update("users_role", array("role_id"=>$this->input->post("")) , array("user_id"=>$id));
```

I hope it helps you.

PS: If you want I can pass you the general_model.php